# App runs on local Tomcat instance, but gives 404 on virtual server with identical software and setup

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, virtual-machine, http-status-code-404, vaadin

I have a Vaadin and Spring Boot app that runs in the Tomcat instance on a local server.

Whenever I deploy it to the Tomcat instance on a virtual server hosted by a provider, I get a 404 and the application log isn't created. There are no errors in any Tomcat logs and Tomcat manager shows the app as running.

I've deployed another Vaadin / Spring Boot app to that same Tomcat instance that's just a static html page and it both runs and creates an application log. I've ran the app on an old mac with the same amount of memory as the virtual server just to rule out a memory issue.

Both my local server and the virtual server are running Debian with the same versions of Java and Tomcat. The only software difference I'm aware of is my local server is Debian 10 and the virtual server is Debian 9. No other software has been installed except UFW which is disabled.

The virtual server has no other firewalls. I tried adding a static html page to the project root, and that gives a 404 too.

I assume any careless errors in coding and configuration are automatically ruled out by the fact that it runs on a local server. How do I debug this?

Comment: Maybe a port mapping issue? For example, the port your app is listening to is not open outside their infrastructure. Which provider are you using? Maybe they have detailed instructions on how to deploy Spring Boot apps.

Comment: Hi Alejandro, lsof shows tomcat listening on 8080. If it was a port issue, you'd think that port issue would prevent the other app from running. I'm currently using Hostwinds, but I had the same issue on A2 about 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Maybe your application was deployed in wrong path, did you get famous  blue tomcat 404 error page?

Comment: Yes, it's the tomcat 404 page. The tomcat logs show the correct context path.

Comment: Most likely the application died on startup.  Make sure you find where the log ends up (might be one of the tomcat log files, might be configured to log somewhere else). If unsure ramp up the logging and configure a fixed location for the file just to continue. Also spring-boot builds you a fat jar you could try to run that standalone on the server just to see what happens (or even ditch tomcat alltogether if you don't need the app server)

Comment: I was able to run the app using the embedded Tomcat in Spring Boot. I guess the lesson is don't install Tomcat if you're using Spring Boot.